# Can grow property deletes spaces and inverts parentheses

Tags: crystal-reports, arabic

My report is written in Arabic. When I activate Can Grow, the report deletes spaces and inverts parentheses. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is how the report looks before activating Can Grow:

[image: []

After:

[image: []

Comment: In both images the difference I see is only numericals are not visible after can grow.. is that your problem?

Comment: @Siva The numbers turned from English to Arabic and the spaces between them and the words were omitted and also the arcs were reversed